# How to execute function once after flask starts in Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I would like to execute a code after the flask server started. Basically I am subscribing to events, but the server does not allow for it as long as my server (callback URI) is not up. But in my app I am also registering the events I am subscribing to.

Any idea how to do this please?

I did

```
app.run()
my_code()
```

but this stops the server.
I tried

```
with app.app_context():
   my_code()
app.run()
```

But this call my code infinitely before running it seems.